# With PHP, how to remove NUL characters when using Zendframework encrypt file filter (uses MYCRPT) with rijndael-256

Tags: php, zend-framework, encryption

When trying decrypt a file, there are several NUL binary characters added to the end of all the files (PDF, XLS, etc.) so they won't open correctly. How do you remove the NUL during decryption? RTRIM does not seem to be any help on the dectryptedbinary datafile (word doc, xls, etc.).

Using rijndael-256 encryption/decryption.

```
readfile(rtrim($encrypt->filter($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])));
```

Trying to do everything in one line for scale efficiency.

Comment: Can you check if there is a byte with value 0x80 right before the NUL characters? It would be nice if you would followup on your questions!

Answer (score 4):

Use something like `rtrim($decrypted, "\0");` to remove the trailing `NUL` characters from your decrypted message.  Since you are using a block cipher (AES), it has to pad the encrypted string out to the block length.

If the end of your file can possible contain valid `NUL` characters then this method may be problematic, and you will need to retain the original message length so you can remove the additional pad at the end.

See [Padding - Cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29) in particular, the section Padding Methods.

Comment: Thanks! I solved this by BASE64 encoding the file first, then encrypting. To decrypt, I decrypt, trim, then BASE64 decode. All working perfectly :)